# How to Handle a Forgotten Password

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, forgot-password

I have a program, written in Java, that communicates with my MySQL server for things such as user accounts, versions, etc. The program is setup so that each user has an account to the server so that my program can communicate with it, but the accounts have *very* limited access. Anyway, when someone "logs in" to my program, it creates a connection with the MySQL server. However, if they forget their password, I want (or rather, would like) my application to be able to reset their password. However, this poses a problem, since there's no account signed into the server that is able to modify the password. Also, I (*obviously*) don't want to hardcode some admin login into the program, due to the obvious threat of decompilation. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the fact that you don't have a website makes this problem much more difficult.  Indeed, you will  simplify the problem immensely by setting up a site, even if it is for the *sole purpose* of resetting users' database passwords.

Second, if you don't have in independent way of identifying the user with a reasonable degree of confidence, then the problem is unsolvable.  If someone presses the "Reset my password" button and says "I am Fred", you have no idea if it was the Fred who pressed the button ... or someone else.  Not even if you could be sure that the "reset" was requested on Fred's computer.

Third, how do you pass the password to the user securely?  Sending passwords by email doesn't cut it.  Even if there is end-to-end secure transmission of the email, the email could still be sitting in the user's mailbox for days, months, years.  (A password reset URL at least has a timeout associated with it ... and the password itself isn't in the email.)

---

In short: my advice is set up a password reset website ... or get the users to submit a request to a help desk and SMS the new passwords to them.

And since you ought to be getting users to change passwords regularly (best practice), you probably *need* that password reset site!

Comment: I honestly wouldn't mind getting a website, and I plan to eventually, but I'm in high school, and have very little experience with building a website. Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you concentrate on your course work.  And if this project is coursework related, then put this "requirement" into the "will not implement" category.

Comment: Unfortunately, the program I'm working on is designed to help students, like myself, in their studying endeavors for the AP Exams in the spring. Therefore, security is not a huge issue, but I would like a way for my dilemma to be resolved before the initial release.

Comment: Well, the only viable solution is a webstite, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you don't have any website support or whatever, you can't really do it... So implement a button in your app, that will trigger a few questions to the user, such as "Login, email etc" that will be mailed to you directly so that you can handle the case...

Or you just simply host a little script on your web server that your app can reach and would take care of generating a new random password and send it to the client. Personaly, I'd never go with the first one, too much stress, script that!